# Upload large files to sharepoint library subfolder using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using PowerShell to upload multiple **large** files to the SharePoint library subfolder.

Using the below link/code I am able to upload files to only to root but not in Subfolder.

How can I upload it to the library subfolders? everything else is working fine.

https://www.sharepointsky.com/upload-large-files-to-sharepoint-online-document-library-using-powershell-csom/

Comment: Some nonsense, it's easier to expand file support in WebApplication and download everything through WebDav, especially since you do not have SP Online.

Comment: @Fox not sure what you talking. If you knw how to do it using powershell please answer

Answer (score 0):

You are adding files to root folder of the document library by using code: `$Docs.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)`

To add files to subfolder you need to get that sub folder first:

```
$folder = $web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($folderUrl)
$ctx.Load($folder)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

then you can add files same way as now

```
$folder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample test script for your reference.

```
$SiteURL = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/"
$libraryName="Testt"
$SPOnlineUserName="user@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$SPOnlinePassword="************."
$fileDirectory="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Downloads"
$TargetFolderRelativeURL ="/sites/dev/Testt/ccc"
Try{
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
}
catch {
Write-host "No dlls found"
}
Function UploadFileInSlice ($ctx, $libraryName, $fileName, $fileChunkSizeInMB) {
$fileChunkSizeInMB = 9
# Each sliced upload requires a unique ID.
$UploadId = [GUID]::NewGuid()
# Get the name of the file.
$UniqueFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fileName)
# Get the folder to upload into.
$Docs = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($libraryName)
$web=$ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($Docs)
$ctx.Load($Docs.RootFolder)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
# Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
$ServerRelativeUrlOfRootFolder = $Docs.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
# File object.
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File] $upload
# Calculate block size in bytes.
$BlockSize = $fileChunkSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024
# Get the size of the file.
$FileSize = (Get-Item $fileName).length
if ($FileSize -le $BlockSize)
{
# Use regular approach.
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($fileName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $UniqueFileName
$folder = $web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($TargetFolderRelativeURL)
$folder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$ctx.Load($folder)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
else
{
# Use large file upload approach.
$BytesUploaded = $null
$Fs = $null
Try {
$Fs = [System.IO.File]::Open($fileName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
$br = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader($Fs)
$buffer = New-Object System.Byte[]($BlockSize)
$lastBuffer = $null
$fileoffset = 0
$totalBytesRead = 0
$bytesRead
$first = $true
$last = $false
# Read data from file system in blocks.
while(($bytesRead = $br.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0) {
$totalBytesRead = $totalBytesRead + $bytesRead
# You've reached the end of the file.
if($totalBytesRead -eq $FileSize) {
$last = $true
# Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size.
$lastBuffer = New-Object System.Byte[]($bytesRead)
[array]::Copy($buffer, 0, $lastBuffer, 0, $bytesRead)
}
If($first)
{
$ContentStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
# Add an empty file.
$fileInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$fileInfo.ContentStream = $ContentStream
$fileInfo.Url = $UniqueFileName
$fileInfo.Overwrite = $true
$folder = $web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($TargetFolderRelativeURL)
$folder.Files.Add($fileInfo)
$ctx.Load($folder)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
# Start upload by uploading the first slice.
$s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($buffer)
# Call the start upload method on the first slice.
$BytesUploaded = $Upload.StartUpload($UploadId, $s)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
# fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
$fileoffset = $BytesUploaded.Value
# You can only start the upload once.
$first = $false
}
Else
{
# Get a reference to your file.
$Upload = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($Docs.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + [System.IO.Path]::AltDirectorySeparatorChar + $UniqueFileName);
If($last) {
# Is this the last slice of data?
$s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($lastBuffer)
# End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload.
$Upload = $Upload.FinishUpload($UploadId, $fileoffset, $s)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host "File upload complete"
# Return the file object for the uploaded file.
return $Upload
}
else {
$s = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($buffer)
# Continue sliced upload.
$BytesUploaded = $Upload.ContinueUpload($UploadId, $fileoffset, $s)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
# Update fileoffset for the next slice.
$fileoffset = $BytesUploaded.Value
}
}
} #// while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
}
Catch {
Write-Host "Error occurred"
}
Finally {
if ($Fs -ne $null)
{
$Fs.Dispose()
}
}
}
return $null
}
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$securePassword=ConvertTo-SecureString $SPOnlinePassword -AsPlainText -Force
$Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($SPOnlineUserName, $securePassword)
foreach($fileName in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
{
$UpFile = UploadFileInSlice -ctx $Context -libraryName $libraryName -fileName $fileName.FullName
$Context.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you .... Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Server relative urls 
must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl" and also error Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "File Not Found."... I am very new to the powershell and sharepoint

Comment: Folder url should start with your site url {/sites/dev/Testt/ccc} not {/library/folder}.

Comment: I am using same "sites/bu-dam/Operations/Customer%20Care/AccDatabase/Test" but getting error Exception calling "StartUpload" with "2" argument(s): "The object is not associa
ted with an object identity or the object identity is invalid." 

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

What Lee gave you is on the right track Jack.  There are a few things you can, and want to change up though.

First - Since you're using relative URLs, add that as a parameter to the function. This is for the part of the URL after your Document Library name (i.e. /sub-folder/sub-folder):

```
 Function UploadFileInSlice ($ctx, $libraryName, $fileName, $FolderRelativeURL)
```

Then - Create a variable that will construct your target URL (remember to replace spaces, and remove commas:

```
$targetURL = "/sites/dev/$($libraryName.Replace(',','').Replace(' ','%20'))$($FolderRelativeURL.Replace(' ','%20'))"
```

Next - Since you're using relative URLs, there's no need to load the root folder. You can still upload to it using its relative URL. You will however want your context to be aware of the target folder for later. So before the meat of the function, you only need these 4 lines to setup your context:

```
$web = $ctx.web
$folder = $web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($targetURL)
$ctx.Load($folder)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

The bit that Lee provided in the "regular approach" will work fine for files that are less than the block size, but in the large file section, you want to use that $upload object. You need that object in order for the rest of the code to upload the slices. This should look familiar when compared to your original source and Lee's answer:

```
$Upload = $folder.Files.Add($fileInfo)
```

Finally - After the first slice (empty file), is uploaded, you need to change the $upload object's reference.  The original code is still looking at the root for the file.  You have to direct it to your relative URL.  Since you loaded your folder into context earlier, you can retrieve the needed property (in this instance, you're getting its ServerRelativeUrl):

```
$Upload = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($folder.ServerRelativeUrl + [System.IO.Path]::AltDirectorySeparatorChar + $UniqueFileName);
```

The reason I have the script constructing 2 different URLs is because $web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl wants a web URL (which means %20 instead of spaces and no commas), and $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl wants a direct URL (which can have spaces; it does not like URLs with %20 in them). You may not have this problem, and can skip some of that code. My users are not nice to me however, and use spaces wherever they can.

As a final note, you may want to add $Filestream.dispose() before the 'return' in the "regular approach" section.  Without it, that file will be locked until the script ends, leaving you unable to access/modify it later if needed.

I hope this helps you out. I too had to scour the internet for how to upload large files into sub-directories.

Comment: The additional parameter isn't necessary I guess, but it makes the function more useful in a script imo.